# Show that $|\sum _{j=1}^n \frac{\cos (2\pi jx)}{j}| \leq C -\log |\sin (\pi x)| $

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis

Show that there exists a constant $C\geq 0$ such that for all $n\geq 1$ : $$|S_n(x)|=|\sum _{j=1}^n \frac{\cos (2\pi jx)}{j}| \leq C -\log |\sin (\pi x)|, \quad \forall x\in ]0,1]. $$

Since $S_n(x)$ converge uniformly on each interval $[\epsilon , 1]$ with $\epsilon >0$, it is suffisant to show that the result is true on a neighbourhood of $0$.

I tried to use an Abel transformation and use the fact that $|\sum _{j=1}^n\cos (2\pi jx)|\leq C'|\sin (\pi x)^{-1}|$. But this majoration is too crude and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed an exercise about Fourier series. We have that:

> $$\log\sin(\pi x) = -\log 2-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(2\pi n x)}{n} $$

holds as an identity over $L^2((0,1))$, since:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\log\sin(\pi x)\,dx = -\log 2$$
follows from considering Riemann sums and the identity:
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{\pi k}{n}=\frac{2n}{2^n},$$
while over $|z|<1$ we have:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n} = -\log(1-z) $$
so we can evaluate the previous identity in $z=e^{2\pi i x}$ by Abel's lemma, then take the real part.

Comment: It's a nice proof, but this only show that $|\sum _{j\geq 1}\frac{\cos (2\pi jx)}{j}|\leq C- \log |sin \pi x |$. I don't see how we can deduce that $\sup _n |\sum _{j= 1}^n\frac{\cos (2\pi jx)}{j}|\leq C- \log |sin \pi x |$.

Comment: @Patissot: once we know the $L^2$ identity, we just need a bound for $$\sum_{n\geq N}\frac{\cos(2\pi n x)}{n},$$ that is converging by Dirichlet's test, and indeed is $\ll\frac{|\cot(2x)|}{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found an alternative proof.

We can write $\sum _{j\geq 1}\frac{\cos (2\pi jx)}{j} =\sum _{j\leq \lambda} \frac{\cos (2\pi jx)-1}{j}+ \sum _{j\leq \lambda}j^{-1}+\sum _{j>\lambda } \frac {cos(2\pi jx)}{j}=A_1+A_2+A_3.$

Since $|\cos (x) -1|\leq x^2/2$ we have : $$ |A_1|\leq \sum _{j\leq \lambda}4\pi ^2 jx^2 \leq C_1\lambda ^2x^2 $$

and : $$ |A_2| \leq  \log (\lambda ) +1$$

By using Abel transform we can show that : $$ |A_3| \leq C_3 (\lambda x)^{-1}.$$

By taking $\lambda =x^{-1}$, we obtain that : $\sum _{j\geq 1}\frac{\cos (2\pi jx)}{j} \leq C' +\log (1/x) \leq C -\log (| \sin (\pi x)|).$

Do you think my proof is correct ?