# Estimate or evaluate the sum: $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\cos k x}{k}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Estimate or evaluate the sum:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\cos k x}{k}$$
where $x\in\mathbb R$.
My approach:
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\cos k x}{k}\Rightarrow f'(x)= - \sum_{k=1}^n \sin k x$$
If we use 
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sin{kx}=\dfrac{1}{\sin{\frac{x}{2}}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(\sin{kx}\cdot\sin{\frac{x}{2}}\right)$$ 
and the identity 
$$\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}=\dfrac{1}{2}(cos(\alpha-\beta)-cos(\alpha+\beta))$$
we obtain
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}\cot(x/2)-\frac{\cos(nx+(x/2))}{2\sin(x/2)}$$
Thus:
$$f(x)-f(a)=\frac{1}{2}\int_a^x\cot(t/2) dt-\int_a^x\frac{\cos(nt+(t/2))}{2\sin(t/2)}dt$$
If we choose initial point at $a=\pi$, we have a known value for $f(a)= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k}$.
My question is the following. I have evaluate the sum, but do you know another method for evaluate (or estimate) this sum?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I am not sure what do you want... do you want the estimation of the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(kx\right)}{k}$ or another method for $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\cos\left(kx\right)}{k}$?

Comment: The finite sum is non-elementary, but the infinite series can be written as a combination of logarithms and exponentials.

Comment: You can show that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\cos\left(kx\right)}{k}\leq C-\log |sin (x/2)|$.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173560/show-that-sum-j-1n-frac-cos-2-pi-jxj-leq-c-log-sin-pi-x

Comment: Sorry, there was a misunderstanding. I meant to write "sum" and not "series".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Assuming that you want to evaluate the *infinite* sum, note that
$$
\frac{\cos kx}{k}
=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\frac{e^{ikx}}{k}\right)+\left(\frac{e^{-ikx}}{k}\right)\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{(e^{ix})^k}{k}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{(e^{-ix})^k}{k}\right).
$$

Comment: Where did the $i$'s go from the second last to last line?