# Estimate $|S_n(x)|=\left|\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{\cos (2\pi \lambda_k x)}{\lambda_k}\right|$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis

We known that there exists a constant $C\geq 0$ such that for all $n\geq 1$ : $$|S_n(x)|=\left|\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{\cos (2\pi kx)}{k}\right| \leq C -\log |\sin (\pi x)|, \quad \forall x\in (0,1]. $$
See, for example: [Show that $|\sum _{j=1}^n \frac{\cos (2\pi jx)}{j}| \leq C -\log |\sin (\pi x)|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173560/show-that-sum-j-1n-frac-cos-2-pi-jxj-leq-c-log-sin-pi-x).

Now, if $\lambda_k$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $\lambda_k-\lambda_{k-1}\geq \gamma>0$ is there a similar estimate for
$$|S_n(x)|=\left|\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{\cos (2\pi \lambda_k x)}{\lambda_k}\right|?$$

Comment: I assume that $\gamma$ is arbitrary, not the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), right?

Comment: @ErikP. Yes! It is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in the original estimate the interval should be (0, 1 **)** instead of (0, 1] because the series in *x* = 1 isn’t different from *x* = 0 and diverges.

Anyway, the answer about estimate in (0, 1), of course, is **no.** We see $\cos(2π λ_k x)$ in the numerator (is it a mistake?), and choosing an arbitrary  0 < *q* < 1 and $λ_k := k/q$ causes the series to diverge in *x* = *q* that belongs to (0, 1). I guess, true original poster’s intent was

$$|S_n(x)|=\left|\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{\cos (2\pi k x)}{λ_k}\right|?$$

for which I don’t know the answer.